# Create an IQueryable from raw sql query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a complex entity framework query (filter, unions, calculations, ...):

```
IQueryable<ViewModel> query = from a in db.Entity1
            where ...
            select new ViewModel
            {
                field1: a.field1,
                field2: a.field1*2 // Calculation example
            };


other_part_of_my_application.DataSource = query;
```

This query object is an IQueryable. This means the query is not executed at this time. The object is send to another part of my application which apply additional filters, sorting and pagination.

I would like to write my query in raw SQL. Is there a way to do that without changing the other part of my application ?

I would like to do something like this:

```
IQueryable<ViewModel> query = I_Dont_know_what<ViewModel>("SELECT field1, (field1*2) as field2 From Entity1 Where ...");

other_part_of_my_application.DataSource = query;
```

My question is what should i put instead of "I_Dont_know_what" ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use FromSqlRaw(Async)

Comment: Thanks but this will execute the query.
I want to get an IQueryable in order to add filter/sort/paging later...

Comment: No, just read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: I have already read it this is why i've said in my original question i want to get an IQueryable ;)

Comment: It returns IQueryable. `context.Set<ViewModel>().FromSqlRaw(…)`. But you have to register `ViewModel` in options builder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried to register the ViewModel in db context with modelBuilder.Query<ViewModel> but i have an error: ModelBuilder does not contains defintion for 'Query'. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Register as a keyless entity

Comment: I have also tried. What i want to do is to "map" query result to a viewmodel class. This viewmodel is not an Entity

Comment: But currently you MUST map - support for non mapped classes are coming in EF Core 7 https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/04/06/query-non-table-classes-raw-sql.html

Comment: great works fine ! thanks